# how to streatch small image with out losing its quality

Tags: android, image

In my app i have to set up a small image as background, to show text and image on it.

1)I tried to set image as background of a layout some thing like 
  `<layout  android:background="imagePath"> <ImageView/> <TextView/></layout>`
2)Tried to show image in web view.
But the image has lost its quality. In iphone we can resiz it like `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:23.0f topCapHeight:15.0`
i want to know what should be the best method for image resizing in android

Comment: make it 9patch there are plenty of tutorials on net just google it

Comment: i have tried to make it 9patch but didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do stretchable background is 9-patch drawable. Android sdk provides instrument for simple creating 9-patches.

Using this you have to manage part of Image which not losing quality.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do stretchable background is [9-patch drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch). Android sdk provides instrument for simple creating 9-patches.